# App display error in iOS7 Xcode5 in MKPolyline

Tags: ios, xcode, mapkit, mkpolyline

I am updating my old app to `iOS7`. In that app i am displaying line over map using `MKPolyline`.
its working fine in `iOS6` and `Xcode 4.6` but doesnt work in my new xcode and displayed error on the codes of `MKPolyline`.

Is apple has change `MapKit Framework`. what should i have to update?

On the `MKPolyline` codes display this error

`Unknown type name 'MKPolyline'`

But if i Control-Click the `MKPolyline` than it will take me to the MapKit class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all i think this is the problem with the `#import` code. You said that this is an old app. please show us the `#import` code for mapkit framework.

If it like this:

```
#import "MapKit/MKMapView.h"
```

than change it to this:

```
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
```

I think this will solve the unknown class error. if still its display error than use `MKGeodesicPolyline` instead of `MKPolyline`. You can find nice explanation [here](https://www.captechconsulting.com/blog/eric-stroh/ios-7-tutorial-series-map-kit).

Hope it help.